# react native navigate to screen from function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to move through screens using React Navigation, the problem lies in the nested return that i use to dynamically render a set of items and doesn't let me use an arrow function to directly navigate, so i have to implement this on a function. My question here is, how do i do that? As far as my internet research went you can only push a new screen after a dialog alert shows up, i don't want that.

I'm attaching the code:

```
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var {width,height} = Dimensions.get('window');

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image
} from 'react-native';
import Pie from 'react-native-pie';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import NaviBarView from './../Commons/NaviBar'
import actions from '../../Redux/actions'

class Main extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        cargando:true,
        cryptoCurrencyValues:{}
    }

    this.onNextPress = this.onNextPress.bind(this);
    this.renderItems = this.renderItems.bind(this);
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps,prevState){
    console.warn('Positivo', Object.keys(nextProps.cryptoCurrencyValues).length)
    if (Object.keys(nextProps.cryptoCurrencyValues).length !== 0){

    }else{
        console.warn('Negativo')
    }
    return null;
}

onNextPress(){

    **//HERE I WANT TO CALL NAVIGATE TO MOVE TO ANOTHER SCREEN**

}

componentDidMount(){
    console.warn('esto una vez')
    this.props.actions.getCryptoValues();
    this.setState({cargando:true})
}

renderItems(){
    var self = this;
    return listData.map(function(cryptoValue,i){
    return(
                <View style={styles.itemContainer} key={i}>
                    <View style={{alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor:'transparent', marginLeft:10}}>
                        <Image source={cryptoValue.img} style={{width:width*0.095, height:height*0.050}} resizeMode={'stretch'}/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{marginLeft:10}}>
                        <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-start',marginTop:15}}>
                            <Text style={{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:18,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{cryptoValue.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-start',marginBottom:10}}>
                            <Text style={{color:'#6e6e6e',fontSize:18}}>{cryptoValue.desc}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{marginLeft:40}}>
                        <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-start',marginTop:15}}>
                            <Text style={{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:18}}>{cryptoValue.price}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-start',marginBottom:10}}>
                            <Text style={{color:'#6e6e6e',fontSize:18}}>{cryptoValue.currency}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor:'transparent', marginLeft:50}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => self.onNextPress()} style={{alignSelf:'center',backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
                            <Image source={require('./../../img/next.png')} style={{width:width*0.035, height:height*0.032}} resizeMode={'stretch'}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View> 
                </View>         
                );
            });
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <NaviBarView/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                <View style={{marginTop:10,flexDirection: 'row',marginTop:10,marginLeft:10,alignItems:'stretch'}}>
                        <Image source={require('./../../img/pie-chart.png')} resizeMode={'stretch'} style={{width:width*0.095, height:height*0.055}}/>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#ffffff',fontWeight:'bold',marginLeft:15,alignSelf:'center'}}>STATUS</Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft:230,alignSelf:'center'}}>
                            <Image source={require('./../../img/reload.png')} resizeMode={'stretch'} style={{width:width*0.065, height:height*0.035}}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                    <View style={{alignSelf:'flex-start',marginTop:50}}>
                        <Pie
                          radius={100}
                          innerRadius={97}
                          series={[10, 20, 30, 40]}
                          colors={['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f', '#ff0']} 
                        />
                    </View>
            </View>

            {this.renderItems()}

        </View>

        );
    }
}

const listData = [
{_id:1,name:'Bitcoin',desc:'Billetera BTC',price:'$141,403.22',currency:'BTC: $11.673,50',img:require('./../../img/bitcoin.png')},
{_id:2,name:'Ethereum',desc:'Billetera ETH',price:'$20200,50',currency:'ETH: $863,40',img:require('./../../img/ethereum.png')},
{_id:3,name:'NEO',desc:'Billetera NEO',price:'$40.401',currency:'NEO: $118,02',img:require('./../../img/neo.png')},
];

const styles = new StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#0d0d0d',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        position:'relative',
    },
    cardContainer:{
        backgroundColor:'#1a1a1a',
        marginTop: 7,
        marginBottom:7,
        marginLeft:7,
        marginRight:7,
        height:height*0.50,
        width:width,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
    itemContainer:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor:'#1a1a1a',
        width:width,
        height:height*0.115,
        marginLeft:7,
        marginRight:7,
        marginBottom:7,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
})

function mapStateToProps (state,props) {
    return {cryptoCurrencyValues: state.cryptocurrencyValues,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not passing the navigation prop when defining my RootStack:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

import createStore from './../../Redux/store';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import MainView from '../Main/Main';
import MainSecondLvlView from '../Main/MainSecondLvl';
import BalanceView from './../Charts/BalanceView'
import MenuView from './Menu'

const store = createStore();

const RootStack = StackNavigator({
    Main: { screen: MainView },
    MainSecondLvl: { screen: MainSecondLvlView},
    Menu:{ screen: MenuView }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
    headerMode: 'none', 
});

export default class App extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RootStack navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
            </Provider>
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Stack Navigator here which is very easy to navigate from one screen to another and as well as in function too...
First.
Install library :-

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Then use it in your class by using import  :-

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
```

export that class

```
export default Project = StackNavigator(
{

  xyz: { screen: xyz },
});
```

After that navigating using function:-

```
onNextPress=()=>
{
  this.props.navigation.navigate('xyz');
}
```

Hope.it will helps you .
Thanx!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, problem was when defining my RootStack, i was not passing the navigation prop.